# Deployment management of a distributed system?

Tags: php, svn, deployment, synchronization

I have a simple script that I wrote in PHP which, once uploaded to a server, does various checks on URLs. So basically, this script would connect from server A, to server B, and check if that server is online. The problem is:

1. It must be live on about 5 servers.
2. One of the 5 will have the extra feature of calling all 5 servers.
3. This will allow you to provide a URL and check the uptime/connectivity of that system from 5 different points in the world.

My questions is... what is the easiest way to manage deployment/updates of this script when located on 5 different servers? I have the code in a SVN repo, but not all 5 servers have shell access. Is there a way I can easily write a script file that will keep the code on a specific folder in sync with all the servers?

Comment: If you don't have shell access on a server, that severely limits your deployment options. Do you have a command-line version of `svn` on those servers? Issuing a `svn up` on a periodic cron would do it, as long as your repository is available (password protected if necessary) over the internet.

Comment: i do have shell account on the main account, and I think Rsync might be the solution for me, but I'm still busy investigating.

Comment: Ah yes, an rsync from a non-shell machine to the repo server might do it. This could be triggered by cron, or (slightly inelegantly) a web script.

Comment: I like the rSync solution. You could also checkout the script on the five servers and have a cron job run `svn up` on the checkouts periodically.